# Centos stream 9 local console login input shown as squares

Tags: linux, centos, io, operating-system, keyboard-layout

I'm after a fresh centos stream 9 install as minimal install, with only English keyboard and only root user.

After installing, I rebooted and got to the login screen. Trying to type "root" for the username, all I'm getting is squares instead of the letters. Obviously login fails. Numbers are shown correctly.

[Example of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS8Sg.jpg)

I'm clueless as I'm new to linux.

Thank you all very much in advance for the help.

Comment: without exacly knowing what went wrong: without any way of logging into the machine troubleshooting this will be quite difficult. You'll most likely be better off installing fresh...

Comment: Or alternatively you could try logging in via SSH if you already completed the network setup and have enabled sshd

Comment: SSH isn't an option, didn't set-up... Its the third time i installed it already, every time it's the same problem

Comment: My guess would be fonts are missing maybe - try a regular install rather than minimal, given you're new to Linux?